# Center an inline element that's next to 2 uncentered elements

Tags: html, css

On my webpage, I have three inline elements, and I want the second one to be centered, and the third to be aligned to the right.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Website
</title>
<style>
.inline1 {display: inline; padding-right: 10px;}
.inline2 {display: inline; text-align: center;}
.inline3 {display: inline; text-align: right; padding-left: 10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h4 class="inline1">
Inline 1
</h4>
<h4 class="inline2">
Inline 2
</h4>
<h4 class="inline3">
Inline 3
</h4>
```

None of these methods worked:

- using position and left in CSS;
- changing parent div display;
- changing text-align of parent div and adding margin between elements;
- changing inline elements to inline-block, flex, table, or tablecell display;

I want to keep the elements on the same line but aligned different horizontally.

Comment: You need to set flex or grid on the parent, not the child elements. Inline elements don't behave the same as inline block or block either in regards to padding or margin

Comment: Did you mean that the 3rd element is to be aligned on the left? i.e. immediately next to the first element?

Comment: Thanks for the correction - it makes quite a difference! Note that some of the answers which have been upvoted and use space-between do NOT center the second element (I suggest you put different length strings into the 3 elements so this is clear).

Comment: @AHaworth No, I meant element1 on the left, element2 in the middle, and element3 on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 3 col grid - where the columns each have equal width - will allow you to place each of the elements as you wish, to left, to center, to right:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Website
  </title>
  <style>
    div {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    
    .inline1 {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .inline2 {
      display: inline;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .inline3 {
      display: inline;
      text-align: right;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h4 class="inline1">
      Inline 1 and some more text
    </h4>
    <h4 class="inline2">
      Inline 2 - centered
    </h4>
    <h4 class="inline3">
      Inline 3
    </h4>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This **almost** didn't work for me, however after changing the display of .inline3 to block and adding float: right; it aligned to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Use a flexbox with `justify-content: space-between`.

```css
.d1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <h4>Inline 1</h4>
  <h4>Inline 2</h4>
  <h4>Inline 3</h4>
</div>

<div class="d1">
  <h4>This value is a quite long one</h4>
  <h4>Centered between the others</h4>
  <h4>Short</h4>
</div>
```

Here is a [complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: This only looks as tho' it centers the middle element because they all have the same length string in this example.

Comment: It is unclear whether the requirement is “in the centre of the viewport”, or “centred between the left and right elements”. This answer does the latter.

Comment: Good point. I'd made a hasty assumption.

Comment: @BrettDonald I mean in the centre of the viewport

Comment: @BrettDonald When I tried your solution, the first element, let's say inline1, warped to the next line. Also, changing width didn't do anything. Am I supposed to display inline1 as inline-block?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried 4 methods by changing children's width and position and making the parent display as flex and table as examples below. please have a look.

```css
DIV{
  position: relative;
}
DIV > *{
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.inline1{ text-align: left   }
.inline2{ text-align: center }
.inline3{ text-align: right  }

/* ------------------------- */
#Width{ width: 100% }
#Width > *{
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc( 100%/3  - 3px )
}

/* ------------------------- */
#Position{
  width: 100%;
  height: 62px;
}
#Position > *{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;

}

/* ------------------------- */
#Flex {
  display: flex
}
#Flex > *{
  flex: 1 1 auto
}

/* ------------------------- */
#Table{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#Table > .row{
  display: table-row;
  height: 62px;
}
#Table > .row > *{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33.33%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Width">
    <h4 class="inline1">
      Inline 1
    </h4>
    <h4 class="inline2">
      Inline 2
    </h4>
    <h4 class="inline3">
      Inline 3
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="Position">
    <h4 class="inline1">
      Inline 1
    </h4>
    <h4 class="inline2">
      Inline 2
    </h4>
    <h4 class="inline3">
      Inline 3
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="Flex">
    <h4 class="inline1">
      Inline 1
    </h4>
    <h4 class="inline2">
      Inline 2
    </h4>
    <h4 class="inline3">
      Inline 3
    </h4>
  </div>
  
  <div id="Table">
    <div class="row">
      <h4 class="inline1">
        Inline 1
      </h4>
      <h4 class="inline2">
        Inline 2
      </h4>
      <h4 class="inline3">
        Inline 3
      </h4>      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I prefer to use flexbox.

Comment: 'I prefer to use flex' - this does not work - try putting different length strings into the 3 elements.

Comment: Hi @AHaworth try to replace `flex: 1 1 auto` to `flex: 1 1 33.33%`
there's also a layout css called 'grid', you might like to have a look.

Comment: Hi, it's not me asking the question! Just commenting. I have already put up grid solution which I find easier to understand, tho' your solutions work.